# Java Selenium multiple table structure, iterate through all

Tags: java, loops, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've got a table with rows inside a row of another table which has many rows (other tables with rows).

Wow. That's confusing. Let me lay it out in front of ya!

```
.//*[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation
/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li[*]
```

The firstTable & rows starts here:

```
 firstTable = /div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[*]
```

The secondTable & rows starts here:

```
 secondTable = firstTable/div/ul/li[*]
```

Here is my code where I am experimenting how to System.out.print all each of the items in the tables (which are within the first table)

```
    List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[*]"));
    List<WebElement> liElements2 = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li[*]"));

    System.out.println(liElements.size());
    System.out.println(liElements2.size());

    for (int i = 1; i < liElements.size()+1; i++) {
    if (i < liElements.size() ){
        WebElement linkElement = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath(".//*[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[" + i + "]"));
        System.out.println(linkElement.getText());
    } else if (i == liElements.size()){
         WebElement linkElement2 = driver
                    .findElement(By
                            .xpath(".//*[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[*]/div/ul/li[" + i + "]"));
        System.out.println(linkElement2.getText());
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that, It will iterate through the first table of tables until there are no more objects to find and then throws error, but it does not move onto the next table to print objects there. It just says OK, printed all elements in this table, but moves on to look for an additional non-existing element in that same table and fails.

I am asking, how can I achieve this?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this from above: System.out.println(liElements2.size());  Correctly prints the size of all contents from each table in the table.

Comment: Have you tried by using tagName? Use findElements(By.tagName("tr")).getText(); If you can provide the html I can try that. Here is the link, it may help you https://github.com/jagdeepjain/datetimepicker-ui-test/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jagdeep/example/datetimepicker/examples/ui/TimePickerExamplesPage.java

Comment: You could improve your xpath a bit. First of all `//*` (in `//*[@id='chatComponent']`) is very time consuming, it's better to provide an actual tag name. Secondly, instead of gazillion of `div`s (especially when you use reference by index - never a good thing) you could just use `//`, i.e. `.//tag[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation//ul/li[*]`

Comment: I'd just go and find the developer that wrote a multiple table structure like that and make sure that he can't ever do it again, sock and a cue ball perhaps... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the following algorithm :

1. Find all the rows in the outer (first) table iterate through the rows.
2. From each row in the outer table, find the rows in each of the inner table and iterate through the inner table rows.

   ```
   // find all the rows in the outer table
   List<WebElement> outerLIElementList = driver.findElements(
           By.xpath(".//*[@id='chatComponent']/div/swx-navigation/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li"));

   System.out.println(outerLIElementList.size());

   // iterate through the rows in the outer element
   for (WebElement outerLIElement : outerLIElementList) {

       // find the inner table rows using the outer table row
       List<WebElement> innerLIElementList = outerLIElement.findElements(By.xpath("//div/ul/li[*]"));

       // iterate through the inner table rows and sysout
       for (WebElement innerLIElement : innerLIElementList) {
           System.out.println(innerLIElement.getText());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: omg it worked.... Thanks so much! This solves reading table rows within table rows flawlessly.